Run Applescript by default in log mode
From AppleScript, I can run another AppleScript with
set myScript to alias ((path to scripts folder as text) & "testScript.scpt")
run script myScript

I can also show the log window, to show progress of the script, with:
tell application "System Events"
  tell application "Script Editor" to activate
  keystroke "3" using command down
  sleep 1
  keystroke "r" using command down
end tell

How can I also show the Messages tab, which shows the result of log commands in a script? (If the new image provider on StackExchange allows, I include an image of this Messages tab.)


Try this. It shows how to select any of the four views.
tell application "Script Editor" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Script Editor"
        
        try
            set mi to menu item "Show Log" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
            select mi
            perform action "AXPress" of mi
        end try
        
        click checkbox "Result" of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
        delay 0.6
        click checkbox "Events" of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
        delay 0.6
        click checkbox "Replies" of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
        delay 0.6
        click checkbox "Messages" of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
        
    end tell
end tell

By the way, applescript can put up a progress bar. See the details here. There are a few questions here on the subject as well.
